# IE Local HTML file with inline Javascript and jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-mobile

I would like to send users an HTML file for local use that utilizes Jquery Mobile. Problem is that Internet Explorer gives a yellow bar with a script warning. I'm assuming that it does not like me loading jQuery and jQuery Mobile remotely. So I decided to try embedding the jQuery files into the html page locally. That works for jQuery, but jQuery Mobile has problems with syntax errors and a bunch of code appears on the HTML page. Is it possible to cut and paste jQuery Mobile source directly into an HTML file?

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
//pasted javascript source
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, but not recommended.

Why not to load the files locally?

You can create a "JS" folder aside the html file and put the .js files there. Then you can just link to the files using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/nameOfFile.js"></script>
```

If you still want to put the entire code on the HTML file, just pay attention to the tags you are creating and the order which the libraries are loaded or placed.

jQuery mobile depends on jQuery, so it has to be after the jQuery in the script tag.

If you are seeing a bunch of code on the HTML, that is a sign of your incorrectly formed HTML. Probably you are closing the script tag on the middle of the code or placing a script tag inside another script tag.

**Edit:**

Seeing your example on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/JBPxL/1) I found the problem to be the `o.write('<script>document.domain="'+u+'"</script>')` snippet on jQuery mobile source. When you put this into a script tag, it closes the tag on the `</script>` string. Maybe a bug on HTML parser, but not sure.

What you have to do is separate the string to not trigger the closing tag:

Change this:

```
'"</script>'
```

To something like this:

```
'"</'+'script>'
```

Just by splitting up the string would suffice.

Comment: I'd like to keep it to one file if possible. This is what I tried:
http://jsfiddle.net/JBPxL/1/